# Upload multiple file, rename and push final name to an array

Tags: php, arrays, file-upload

I'm uploading multiple file, the problem is that I'm not able to merge the file result.
lets begin by putting the form this is the code:

```
<form>
<input name="datas[{{$index}}][name]" type="text">
<input name="datas[{{$index}}][pics]" type="file">
</form>
```

That will output, something like this.

```
<form>
<input name="datas[0][name]" type="text">
<input name="datas[0][pics]" type="file">
<input name="datas[1][name]" type="text">
<input name="datas[1][pics]" type="file">
<input name="datas[2][name]" type="text">
<input name="datas[2][pics]" type="file">
</form>
```

as many as the user need, I'm using angularJS to repeat the inputs...
that will output an array that is use to save the data in json format.. in the DB.

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [name] => Marco
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [name] => Polo
        )

    [2] => Array
        (
            [name] => John
        )

)
```

now to move my file I use this...

```
if(isset($_FILES['datas'])){
    foreach($_FILES['datas']['tmp_name'] as $key) {
        $file_tmp = $key['pics'];
        foreach($_FILES['datas']['name'] as $keys) {
            $file_name = $keys['pics'];
            move_uploaded_file($file_tmp, $f_imgs.rand().$file_name);
        }
    }
}
```

Up to this point everything is "fine", I got the file and I got the name, but I can save the information just like that because latter on I have to retrieve it and it will be a mess...
the idea is the following:
1.- I need to rename the file with the users name if the file is named:
pictures_01.jpg I need to add the user name so the file's name will be
name_pictures_01.jpg instead of 33424_pictures_01.jpg, right now I'm using rand() instead of time(), since the user will upload 5 or 10 files at the same time and the time could be the same hence it will override the files name...

2.- Once the files has been moved and renamed with the users name, I need to add that final name to the array before the json_encode, so the final array will be something like:

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [name] => Marco
            [img] => Marco_picures_01.jpg
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [name] => Polo
            [img] => Polo_picures_01.jpg
        )

    [2] => Array
        (
            [name] => John
            [img] => John_picures_01.jpg
        )

)

)
```

Now to push the the [img] key with the value I use this code:

```
foreach ($arrDatas as $ki => $gc) {
    foreach($_FILES['datas']['name'] as $keys) {
        $file_name = $keys['pics'];
        $arrDatas[$ki]['img'] = $file_name;
    }
    }
```

But that is not working because the rename of the file and the array push are separately I have no way of knowing what the name was!...

Thank you for taking the time...

Comment: Your all inputs are of file type ? is it a typo ??

Comment: that was a typo, thanks.